Installing Bazzite- Hit control + alt + F4 to open the log window, now I can't close it
I was installing bazzite and it was being slow so I took a look at the log with a key combination I found on google, control + alt + f4. The log showed up, but I haven't been able to get it to close, I've tried control + alt + F1-F10 but none of them seem to work. It's not frozen or anything as I can still type in the log. I really don't want to restart the installation from scratch if I can keep from it, because the laptop is really old and it took forever.
How can I exit the log window and go back to the installation screen?
